# getting segmentation fault in PrintArray() function

Tags: arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

```
class Array
{
    int sizeX, sizeY;
    int **array;

public:

    void EnterElements()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeX; i++)
        {
            cout << "Enter Elements Of Row:" << i+1 <<endl;
            for(int j = 0; j < sizeY; j++)
            {
                cin >> array[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    Array()
    {
        sizeX = sizeY = 2;

        array = new int*[sizeX];
        for(int i = 0; i<sizeX; i++)
        {
            array[i] = new int[sizeY];
        }
    }

    Array(int x, int y)
    {
        sizeX = x;
        sizeY = y;

        array = new int*[sizeX];
        for(int i = 0; i<sizeX; i++)
        {
            array[i] = new int[sizeY];
        }
    }

    Array(Array &t)
    {
        sizeX = t.sizeX;
        sizeY = t.sizeY;

        array = new int* [sizeX];
        for(int i = 0; i<sizeX; i++)
        {
            array[i] = new int [sizeY];
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<sizeX; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<sizeY; j++)
            {
                array[i][j] = t.array[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    void PrintArray()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<sizeX; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; i<sizeY; j++)
            {
                cout << (int)array[i][j] << "\t";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    Array& operator *(Array array2)
    {
        Array temp(this->sizeY, array2.sizeX);

        if(this->sizeY != array2.sizeX)
        {
            cout << "Cant Multiply" << endl;
            return temp;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < sizeX; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < sizeY; j++)
            {
                for(int k = 0; k < sizeX && k < sizeY; k++)
                {
                    temp.array[i][j] += this->array[i][k]*array2.array[k][j];
                }
            }
        }

        return temp;
    } 
};

int main()
{
    Array a(3,3), b(3,3);
    a.EnterElements();
    b.EnterElements();

    a.PrintArray();
    b.PrintArray();
    Array c(a*b);
    c.PrintArray();

    return 0;
}
```

trying to multiply two matrices using oop but getting a segmentation fault. I am using double pointers. pls, help me resolve this issue. Also, any suggestions/improvements to the code will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> help me resolve this issue

You are allocating dynamic memory in the constructor, but never delete it. That's a memory leak (but not the cause of your crash).

You also neglected to implement copy constructor and assignment operator, violating the [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

Now to the actual problem: compiling your program (after adding missing `#include`) produces:

```
t.cc:80:15: warning: reference to local variable ‘temp’ returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
```

This warning comes from here:

```
   Array& operator *(Array array2)
    {
        Array temp(this->sizeY, array2.sizeX);
...
        return temp;
    }
```

Returning a reference to a local variable is bad, because the reference does not refer to a valid object as soon as the `operator*()` returns, so your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Fixing above bug, we come to the next (hard to spot) one:

```
    void PrintArray()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<sizeX; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; i<sizeY; j++)   // wrong variable used for loop limit (should be j)
            {
                cout << (int)array[i][j] << "\t";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @ayushkapoor If the answer helped you, upvote it. If it answered your question, accept it as the answer.